# SymPy lambdify with dot()

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

Take an undefined function that happens to be named `dot`, and make it part of `lambdify`:

```
import numpy
import sympy


class dot(sympy.Function):
    pass

x = sympy.Symbol('x')

a = sympy.Matrix([1, 0, 0])
f = sympy.lambdify(x, dot(a.T, x))

x = numpy.array([3, 2, 1])
print(f(x))
```

Surprise: This actually works!

Apparently, the string `"dot"` is somehow extracted and replaced by an implementation of the dot-product. Does anyone know which?

The result of the above is `[3]`. I would, however, like to get the scalar `3`. (How) can I modify `f()` to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a `sympy` user however quoting the documentation for [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html?highlight=lambdify#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) it says:

> If not specified differently by the user, **SymPy functions are replaced
>   as far as possible by either `python-math`, `numpy` (if available) or
>   `mpmath` functions - exactly in this order.** To change this behavior, the
>   “modules” argument can be used. It accepts:
>
> - the strings “math”, “mpmath”, “numpy”, “numexpr”, “sympy”
> - any modules (e.g. math)
> - dictionaries that map names of sympy functions to arbitrary functions
> - lists that contain a mix of the arguments above, with higher priority given to entries appearing first.

So it seems that if you have `python-math` installed it will use that, if not but you have `numpy` installed it will use `numpy`'s version, otherwise `mpmat` and then describes how to modify this behaviour.

In your case just provide a `modules` value that is a dictionary that maps the name `dot` to a function that return a scalar as you want.

---

An example of what I mean:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sympy
>>> class dot(sympy.Function): pass
... 
>>> x = sympy.Symbol('x')
>>> a = sympy.Matrix([1,0,0])
>>> f = sympy.lambdify(x, dot(a.T, x), modules=[{'dot': lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y)[0]}, 'numpy'])
>>> y = np.array([3,2,1])
>>> print(f(y))
3
>>> print(type(f(y)))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

As you can see by manipulating the `modules` argument you can achieve what you want. My implementation here is absolutely naive, but you can generalize it like:

```
>>> def my_dot(x, y):
...     res = np.dot(x, y)
...     if res.ndim == 1 and res.size == 1:
...         return res[0]
...     return res
```

This function checks whether the result of the normal `dot` is a scalar, and if so returns the plain scalar and otherwise return the same result as `np.dot`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! `dot()` itself isn't the culprit I believe, more the fact that `sympy.Matrix([1,2,3])` gets translated into a 2-dimensional vector `numpy.array([[1,2,3]])`. This makes numpy's `dot` return an array.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I've added an example of how to achieve what you want using that `modules` argument.  As you can see it does work. I have no idea if there are other ways to achieve this without providing your small custom function.

Comment: In general, when you lambdify a function to a numpy function, you should expect the output to be an array, since that is what all numpy functions output.